# Given a bounded above sequence such that $x_{n+1}-x_n \ge -{1\over 2^n}$, prove that $x_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Prove that a bounded above sequence converges given it satisfies the following property: 
>   $$
> x_{n+1}-x_n \ge -{1\over 2^n}\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$

Since the sequence is bounded above, by definition we have:
$$
\exists M \in\Bbb R: x_n \le M, \forall n\in\Bbb N
$$

By reversing the sign:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_{n} \ge -{1\over 2^n} \iff x_{n} - x_{n+1} \le {1\over 2^n}
$$

Then I tried to consider a list of inequalities:
$$
x_1 - x_2 \le {1\over 2^1}\\
x_2 - x_3 \le {1\over 2^2}\\
x_3 - x_4 \le {1\over 2^3}\\
\cdots\\
x_{n} - x_{n+1} \le {1\over 2^n}
$$

If we now sum up the inequalities one may obtain:
$$
x_1 - x_2 + x_2 - x_3 + x_3 - x_4 + \cdots + x_{n} - x_{n+1} \le \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over 2^k}
$$

By telescoping we obtain:
$$
x_1 - x_{n+1} \le \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over 2^k}
$$

So:
$$
x_1 - x_{n+1} \le 1 - {1\over 2^n} \iff \\ 
M \ge x_{n+1} \ge x_1 - 1 + {1\over 2^n}
$$

I'm not sure about where to go from here. How to prove what's in the problem statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you write

- $x_n = x_1 - \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_k- x_{k+1})}_{convergent}$

It follows the convergence of $(x_n)$