# $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded above sequence such that $x_{n+1} - x_n \ge a_n$, where $\sum a_k$ converges. Prove $x_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded above sequence satisfying the following property: 
>   $$
> x_{n+1} - x_n \ge \alpha_n\tag1
> $$ 
>   where $\alpha_n$ is such that 
>   $$
> \exists \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k
> $$
>   Prove $\{x_n\}$ converges.

I'm trying to generalize the idea from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156905/given-a-bounded-above-sequence-such-that-x-n1-x-n-ge-1-over-2n-prove). Below are some thoughts.

First denote:
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k
$$

Since $S_n$ is convergent then it must be bounded both below and above. Let:
$$
y_n = x_n - S_{n-1}
$$

Since $x_n$ is bounded above and $-S_n$ is also bounded above (by convergence of $S_n$), then it must follow that $y_n$ is also bounded above:
$$
\exists M\in\Bbb R: y_n \le M, \forall n\in\Bbb N \tag2
$$
Rewrite $(1)$ as:
$$
x_{n+1} \ge x_n + \alpha_n
$$

Now subtract $S_n$ from both sides:
$$
\underbrace{x_{n+1} - S_n}_{y_{n+1}} \ge x_n - S_n + \alpha_n = \underbrace{x_n - S_{n-1}}_{y_n}
$$

That means $y_n$ is monotonically increasing. By $(2)$ we know $y_n$ is bounded. Finally by monotone convergence theorem:
$$
\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}y_n \implies \exists\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n - S_{n-1})
$$

Which in terms means that $x_n$ is also convergent. I would like to ask for a verification of the proof above or/and point to mistakes in case of any. Thank you!

Comment: You claim $y_n=x_n-S_{n+1}$ is bounded above. A sufficient condition is that both $x_n$ and $-S_{n-1}$ are bounded above, i.e. that $x_n$ is bounded above and that $S_{n-1}$ is bounded below. Your argument would not work if $S_n$ were only bounded above, but the convergence of $\sum\alpha_k$ ensures boundedness both ways, so the argument can easily be fixed.

Comment: @Thorgott that’s an important point you brought up. Thank you. I will update the post once I get back to my laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, nicely done!

Just as an illsutration of how $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ can shorten such arguments:

As $x_n\geq x_m+\sum_{k=m}^n \alpha_k$ for all $m\leq n$ we have
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(x_m+\sum_{k=m}^n \alpha_k\right)=x_m+\sum_{k=m}^\infty \alpha_k
$$
and then taking $\limsup_{m\to\infty}$ on the right side we get
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n\geq\limsup_{m\to\infty}\left(x_m+\sum_{k=m}^\infty \alpha_k
\right)=\limsup_{m\to\infty}x_m+\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=m}^\infty \alpha_k=\limsup_{m\to\infty}x_m
$$
so $\{x_n\}$ converges.